# removing duplicate entries-- variant in matlab

Tags: matlab, duplicates, duplicate-data

I have A matrix part of which looks like this :

```
4080530 92 -- rid of this 
4085908 92 -- keep this
4086589 93 -- rid
4091453 93 -- rid
4104393 93 -- rid
4112841 93 -- rid
4122958 93 -- rid
4130815 93 -- rid
4142617 93 -- rid
4152386 93 -- keep this
4230963 94
4242541 94
4243222 95
4253979 95
```

In col 2 it can be seen that some entries are repeated. I want to get rid of some of these duplicate entries. In each case I only want to keep the last value. The number of times the value is repeated need not be fixed, hence the issue. Any ideas on how I can about this.

I am currently using some of the ideas here to come up with a fix [this link](http://www.mathworks.ch/matlabcentral/answers/19042-finding-duplicate-values-per-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do just that:

```
[~, I] = unique(A(:,2)),     
B = A(I,:);
```

Breakdown:

- the `unique` command will output the unique, sorted version of the second column of `A`, and its indices (`I`)
- These indices can be used to extract the rows from `A` you want.

Comment: Note that unique does retain the last element of a set of duplicates, not the first, so it does exactly what was asked for here. But in the case of a sorted vector as we have here, find(diff(A(:,2))) will also suffice for this purpose.